# Telerik Grid Client side sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

Is there a way in the Telerik MVC grid to tell the client side sort to sort by an alternate value than the bound value

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Icon).Template(p => p.Icon).ClientTemplate("<#=Icon#>")
```

I don't want to base the sort on The icon which is an image tag, but rather on some Id column in a hidden field. Is this possible?
Also I think I would run into a similar problem when doing client side sorting of dates if I bind my grid to a formated date, and not the raw DateTime fom the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Template(p => p.Icon).ClientTemplate("<#=Icon#>");
```

This way I can maintain the image during client sort, but still order by Id